# How can I pass JSON formatted data to a controller action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I am new to ASP.NET Core MVC and I am struggling sending data back to the controller from the page, i.e. data binding. The page has 81 text boxes on it (I am writing an application to solve a Sudoku puzzle). I first attempted to send back the page to the controller with a "submit" button but I could not get anything to bind to the parameters.

So, after some thought I decided to try using an ajax call which would allow me to see if any errors were occurring on the page. I cannot get binding to work with this approach either. I have read many articles on the internet but just cannot get binding to work.

Here is the javascript:

```
// Matrix grid is an array of MatrixGrid objects.  To simplify testing, I am sending only one MatrixGrid  object.
var send = JSON.stringify(MatrixGrid[0]);

     var StartSolving = $.ajax({
        url: '/Solver/Solve',
        method: 'POST',
        data: send,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'JSON'
    });
```

Here is the controller method signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Solve([FromBody] Matrix send)
{
    // ...
}
```

and here is the Matrix class:

```
namespace Sudoku.Models
{
    public class Matrix
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public int Col { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The `MatrixGrid` javascript object appears to be formatted correctly, as this snippet shows (copied directly from developer tools):

```
send: "{"Row":0,"Col":0,"Value":0}"
```

Sometimes, I get a 415 error; sometimes, I get a null value in the parameter.

Any tips or even links to articles would be appreciated.  And thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `contentType` when configuring your `$.ajax` request.

i.e. add the following to your `$.ajax` request

```
 contentType: "application/json"
```

As mentioned in the [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) documentation, `dataType` is only for what you're expecting to get back from the server as opposed to what you're sending.